# express.js - Run python script on form-submit using POST & routing

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I have installed `python-shell` per the instructions on [this site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) and am able to get this code to run on **test.ejs** on page load:

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
var options = {
    scriptPath: '/nodeGit/scripts',
};

PythonShell.run('my_script.py', options, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('finished');
});
```

I get this to run on **test.ejs** page load by putting it in **test.js**. 
 The portion of **test.js** regarding my **test.ejs** page looks like this:

```
exports.test = function(req, res,callback){

   PythonShell.run('my_script.py', options, function (err, results) {
       if (err) throw err;
  // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution 
  console.log('results: %j', results);
});

// The functions below were not written by me but were left in to show how functions are written(?) in hopes that it helps

    async.auto({

        getData: function get_data(callback){
            Images.findAll({where: {uploaded: 1}})
            .then(function(getData){
                    callback(null, getData);
                })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.log("*******Did not return Image Info ********");
                callback(err);
            });
        }
    function done(err, results){
        callback({
            userList: results.getUser,
            imageList : results.getData,
            user: results.verifyUser,
        });
    });
}
```

Instead of running the script on page-load, I want to call it when I submit an HTML form (& pass in the form's parameters). How would I go about that?

Comment: None of the posted code is related to a web server handling requests. are you asking how to do a post in express? https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: It seems I was. I'm not sure how to apply that information to what I have but routing the post request to call a function is what I need to do..